# How to handle the close event of Bootstrap popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my mvc application I have used one bootstrap popup, I need to check whether any changes are made in textboxes in this popup before closing this window, and give an option to save this before closing. How can I handle the close event of bootstrap popup window?
I have tried

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

It will only fire after the close event.

Comment: Look at [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Comment: attach a mutation observer to the modal form fields and trigger your function in that code block.

Comment: @HimanshuRaval i have mentioned this in my question that this will fire only after the close event,

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221637/prevent-bootstrap-3-modal-from-closing-when-the-form-has-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hide.bs.modal` event..

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //do something..
})
```

Example: http://www.codeply.com/go/wTys5mP4nw

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that we cannot handle here because it will fire only after closing the popup

Comment: This is the `hide` not `hidden` event. It will allow you to conditionally prevent closing.